# MobileFirst V6.3 folder common/js/services in design perspective

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I want create a folder named “services” below “common/js”. Unfortunately, Eclipse seems to get confused with this name while in MFP Design perspective. It doesn’t display the content of the folder, but instead the same services I can see in the services folder in the project root.

As soon as I rename my folder to something else, everything is fine again. 
This is no big issue, but can be interesting understand if a sort of filter is applied in Design perspective.

Comment: Can you provide a more tangible example? I've created a "services" folder under "common\js" and copied various files into it and could see them all in the Project Explorer view as well as in the Design perspective > Properties view.

Comment: This is resolved for vNext of MFP.

Answer (score 0):

If you will open the Navigator view, in either Java EE or Design perspectives you will see the files that you place in the common\js\services folder. You will also see the files' properties in the Design perspective's Properties view.

You will not see them if you are in the Project Explorer view, in either Java EE or Design perspectives.

It's an odd one. We'll take a look.

Comment: Yes services is a curiously reserved word ... there is a workaround, will dig it out.

Comment: I'm betting it has to do with the servics folder in a project's structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is a curious little default setting in Eclipse, to make your services folder visible:

In the project explorer, select the little down arrow in the top right, in the resulting Menu select **Customise View**.

Select the **Content** tab and uncheck the **Services Navigator Content** option.

Comment: Actually we did find some issues and they are being looked at.